# is it better to retrieve a model once using aliases or doing that several times separately?

Tags: model, getmodel

Is it better to use this :-

```
    $subcat= $_brands = $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
```

or this :-

```
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
        $subcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $_brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
```

Answer (score 1):

depends on how u use it...

PHP creates references to objects.

```
$cat1 = $cat2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$cat3 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')

$cat1->setId(1);
$cat2->setId(2); // $cat1 also gets overwritten
$cat3->setId(3);

echo $cat1->getId(); // 2
echo $cat2->getId(); // 2
echo $cat3->getId(); // 3
```

So you could get unexpected results if u use it wrong.